# Query performance of non clustered index during inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

We have two table in a inner join query. Which of the below options is recommended for high performance when there are millions of records in both the tables.

NOTE: We have a non-clustered index on the foreign key column. We don't have enough data to verify the performance in the development environment. Also there might be more tables come into this join with INNER or LEFT joins.

Tables:

```
Subscriber(SID(PK), Name)
Account(AID(PK),SID(FK), AName)
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Account A
INNER JOIN Subscriber S ON S.SubscriberID=  A.SubscriberID
WHERE 
S.SubscriberID = @subID -- option 1
A.SubscriberID = @subID -- option 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not make any difference which column you put the predicate on.

SQL Server can see the `S.SubscriberID=  A.SubscriberID` condition and create an "implied predicate" for the other column anyway.

This does become a cross join (between the filtered rows from both sides) then as [discussed here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/implied-predicates-and-query-hints/ba-p/383545)

Comment: As I think about this, I don't think it makes a difference.  The row in `a` is going to be found using the primary key index -- whether through the `on` or the `where`.  The rows in `b` are going to be found using the secondary index.  That is for any reasonable execution plans.

Comment: Yeah, the query will be treated as `SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT *
FROM Account
WHERE SubscriberID = @subID
) A CROSS JOIN 
(
SELECT *
FROM Subscriber 
WHERE SubscriberID = @subID
) S` - both of the predicates against the base tables can be satisfied with index seeks subject to normal considerations about whether the index is covering and expected number of rows